# How to remove ng-tns class which is adding automatically while using angular 2 animation

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, angular2-animation

```
@Component({
  ...
  animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)'}),
        animate('200ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate('200ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)'}))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
```

I have something like this in my code to create animation on click of a button.

It keeps on adding ng-tns  class like ng-tns-c4-24  to many of tags in code automatically which is affecting testing scripts .

Is there any way I can disallow that class to get added automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51896805/angular-material-ng-tns-class-changes-margin-of-items-in-my-table-can-use-css-t), angular material adds those classes. You may have to edit your tests to filter through the classes.